# Defining multi dimensional array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm having an issue with my multidimensional arrays.

I'm building this super basic reservation system for a project which requires tickets for a movie theatre be 'booked'.

I've added a form which posts its results to an array in `$_SESSION`, my data goes in fine. However building a 'cart' section that displays the contents of this array isn't going smoothly for me at all, I keep running into undefined array errors

```
array(1) {
 ["tickets"]=>
  array(14) {
    [0]=>
    array(20) {
      ["movie"]=>
      string(2) "AF"
      ["day"]=>
      string(8) "Thursday"
      ["time"]=>
      string(3) "3pm"
      ["SA"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TSA"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["SP"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TSP"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["SC"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TSC"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["FA"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["TFA"]=>
      string(6) "300.00"
      ["FC"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TFC"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["B1"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TB1"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["B2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TB2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["B3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TB3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["price"]=>
      string(6) "300.00"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(20) {
      ["movie"]=>
      string(2) "AC"
      ["day"]=>
      string(6) "Monday"
      ["time"]=>
      string(3) "9pm"
      ["SA"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TSA"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["SP"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TSP"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["SC"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TSC"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["FA"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TFA"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["FC"]=>
      string(1) "5"
      ["TFC"]=>
      string(6) "100.00"
      ["B1"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TB1"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["B2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TB2"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["B3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["TB3"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["price"]=>
      string(6) "100.00"
    }
}
```

Here's my loop:

```php
$cart = $_SESSION["tickets"];

$tab = "\t"; // tab
$return = "\r"; // return

foreach ($cart as $key => $a) {
    echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 custom-col">';

    foreach ($a as $value) {

        if (!$value == 0) {
            echo '<div class="col-xs-6 teaser-title">';
            echo $tab.$value.$return;
            echo '</div>';
        };

    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

I'd like to be able to list out the ticket types (all the two letter variables) by their code and display the subtotal or quantity they have (if they have any).

I can get the values fine, but just not the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the labels you could get them into a variable in the inner foreach declaration...

```
foreach ($cart as $key => $a) {
    echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 custom-col">';

    foreach ($a as $index => $value) {

        if (!$value == 0) {
            echo '<div class="col-xs-6 teaser-title">';
            echo $index.$tab.$value.$return;
            echo '</div>';
        };

    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```